# How to replace multiple characters in swift 3

Tags: swift

I'm trying to convert the parts of code that Xcode couldn't convert to Swift3

In swift 2.3 to replace multiple characters in a string I used :

```
var phone = "+ 1 (408)-456-1234"
phone = phone.replaceCharacters("  ) ( -   ‑", toSeparator: "")
```

this should give **+14084561234**

In swift 3 I'm using this :

```
phone = phone.replacingOccurrences(of: " |(|)|-", with: "z",options: .regularExpression)
```

this code gives **+1(408)4561234**

How to replace multiple characters in a string (Swift3)?

but this is not working correctly ? any ideas

Comment: Could you please describe what exactly you want to do? It's obvious your Swift 3 code doesn't contain a valid regular expression.

Comment: I think it's clear. post updated

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to fix the regular expression to create a set of characters you want to remove, e.g.:

```
var phone = "+ 1 (408)-456-1234"
phone = phone.replacingOccurrences(of: "[ |()-]", with: "", options: [.regularExpression])
print(phone) // +14084561234
```

but a better solution is to create a set of characters you want to keep and remove all the others:

```
phone = phone.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^\\d+]", with: "", options: [.regularExpression])
```

Answer (score 5):

Brackets in regular expressions means group. By other words they have to be escaped:

```
var phone = "+ 1 (408)-456-1234" 
phone = phone.replacingOccurrences(of: " |\\(|\\)|-", with: "",options: .regularExpression)
// "+14084561234"
```

But it can be simplified by enumeration of characters:

```
var phone = "+ 1 (408)-456-1234" 
phone = phone.replacingOccurrences(of: "[-() ]", with: "",options: .regularExpression)
// "+14084561234"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
var phone = "+ 1 (408)-456-1234"
let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: " )(-‑")
phone = phone.components(separatedBy: characterSet).joined(separator: "")
```